# Trying to enable and disable css files through javascript

Tags: javascript, css, dom, dom-events

I have 2 different css files, I want to use them both dynamically. I have a mobile preview button that will change to another css file, and also change the same button text to Desktop Preview, and I want the css to change to the original file. I only being able to change to the second file when pressing mobile preview, but after pressing the same button I get an error
`"TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'."`

This is my code:

```
mobileBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const mobileLink = document.createElement('link');
    mobileLink.rel = 'stylesheet';
    mobileLink.type = 'text/css';
    mobileLink.href = 'styles-no-media-query.css'
    document.head.appendChild(mobileLink);

    const currentStyleSheet = document.querySelector('link[href="styles2.css"]');
    const alternativeStyleSheet = document.querySelector('link[href="styles-no-media-query.css"]');

    if (currentStyleSheet) {
      currentStyleSheet.remove();
      document.head.appendChild(alternativeStyleSheet);
      btnText.textContent = 'Desktop Preview';
    } else {
      alternativeStyleSheet.remove();
      document.head.appendChild(currentStyleSheet);
      btnText.textContent = 'Mobile Preview';
    }
});
```

the `currentStyleSheet` returns null after pressing the button, could not figure out why. Tried to make the same as the `mobileLink` but as a `desktopLink` which did not work.

Would appreciate a bit of help here. Thanks!

Comment: Apparently there is no link with href "styles2.css"

Comment: You can disable a stylesheet by adding an attribute called "media" with an invalid value.

Comment: on switching to mobile, you do this: `currentStyleSheet.remove();` but that stylesheet is not added again to the DOM anywhere in your code

Comment: Setting the `disabled` property to true can also be used to make a `link`-ed stylesheet not apply.

Comment: What you currently have is one-off code. When you remove a stylesheet from the DOM, it can't be selected with a DOM method anymore. Rather load all the stylesheets needed and use [disabled property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/StyleSheet/disabled) to disable the ones not needed.

Comment: Your main problem, as GrafiCode pointed, that you remove the link element. On the next click you get the error, b/c there is no more link element in the DOM. I would provide a working example, if I understood what's the purpose of the mobileLink link element? You have 2 <link>-s. Why this mobileLink one, what was your idea?

Comment: @d.k Thanks man. the purpose is so I can dynamically load a css file when the click occurs. without it I get the same error on the first click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided with your attempt to dynamically add a  element in your click handler, I'd suggest, that you try another approach.

Just have 1  element and change its attributes (mainly the href one, but other you may need to change other ones too) in the click handler.

Add a link element in your document with an `id='my-link-el'`.

Then you'll be able to get it and just check & change its href attribute (the example should work provided you have that `btnTxt` variable defined and holding an appropriate value):

```
mobileBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const linkEl = document.querySelector('#my-link-el');
  const currentStyleSheetHref = 'styles2.css';
  const alternativeStyleSheetHref = 'styles-no-media-query.css';

  if (linkEl.href.endsWith(currentStyleSheetHref)) {
    linkEl.href = alternativeStyleSheetHref;
    btnText.textContent = 'Desktop Preview';
  } else {
    linkEl.href = currentStyleSheetHref;
    btnText.textContent = 'Mobile Preview';
  }
});
```